# Pandas merging 2 DataFrames into one graph

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two pandas dataframes. One dataframe needs to be displayed as a line graph and another as a scatter plot on the same graph.

This plots the first dataframe:

```
line = pd.read_csv('nugt_daily.csv',parse_dates=['Date'])
line = line.sort_values(by='Date')
line.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
line['Close'].plot(figsize=(16, 12))
```

I want to plot the following dataframe on top of the previous graph - but as a scatter plot (rather than a line graph):

```
points = pandas.read_csv('test_doc.csv')
points = points.sort_values(by='Date')
points.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
points.plot(figsize=(16, 12))
```

How can I achieve this? When I run the two codes one after the other, I see two separate graphs for each dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return_type='axes'` to get `df1.scatterplot` to return a matplotlib Axes object. Then pass that axes to the second call to linegraph using `ax=ax`. This will cause both plots to be drawn on the same axes.

Try:

```
ax = df1.plot()
df2.plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: sorry, can you please elaborate on that? What changes do I need to make to the code I already copied with the question? Sorry, for the bother but I am just getting started with matplotlib.